# Finding cardinality of sets composed of a difference set $\bar A= \{x-y \ | \ \forall x,y\in A \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For a non empty set $A$ of real numbers, let $\bar A= \{x-y \ | \ \forall x,y\in A  \}$ be the difference set of $A$.
>
> Find the cardinality of the following sets:
>
> - $B= \{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z) | \bar A\subseteq(-1,1)  \}$
> - $C= \{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R) | \bar A=\{-1,0,1\}   \}$
> - $D= \{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb R) | \bar A\subseteq(-1,1)\}$

Okay, so first let's see if I understand the notations, $B$ has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$ because all the elements must be equal to themselves $(x=y)$ and we know that $|\mathbb Z|=|\mathbb N|=\aleph_0$.

For $C$ for all $x,y$ we must have $x-y\lt 2$, I see that the cardinality must be $\frak c$ but I don't know how to show it.

The last one, $D$, I'm not sure how to read it but it must be at least $\frak c$. I don't know how to show it.

Comment: I don't understand the notation: $(-1,0,1)$ in the definition of $C$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see that $B$ is just the set of singletons from $\mathbb{Z}$. It seems that $C$ is the collection $\left\{\{x,x+1\}|x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$, so you're right about those two cardinalities.

The third one, $D$, should include any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that has diameter less than $1$. (It also includes sets such as $(0,1)$ with diameter $1$, but those won't affect the cardinality.) Therefore, every subset of the interval $(0,1-\epsilon)$ is included in $D$, so the cardinality of $D$ is at least $2^{\frak{c}}$. It can't be greater than that, because that's the cardinality of the entire power set of $\mathbb{R}$, so we've got that the cardinality of $D$ is $2^{\frak{c}}$.

Comment: You mean a diameter of less than 2 no ? 

Also, how do you formally show all three of the cardinalaties ?

Comment: No, I mean less than 1. A set with diameter greater than $1$ includes differences greater than $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: As for formal arguments, $B$ and $C$ are fairly straightforward, so you can just write them down as sets, like I did for $C$ above. You can put $B$ and $C$ in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively, so they have matching cardinalities.

Comment: It's more complicated with $D$, but the argument goes like this: The cardinality of $D$ is $\leq 2^{\frak{c}}$ because it's a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. It's also $\geq 2^{\frak{c}}$ because it has a proper subset of that cardinality. Therefore it equals $2^{\frak{c}}$.

Comment: But the difference between 1 and -1 is 2...

Comment: That's right, the difference between $1$ and $-1$ is $2$. Therefore, if $1$ and $-1$ are both in the set, $2$ would have to be in the difference set. All it takes is $0$ and $1$ in the set to get $1$ and $-1$ in the difference set.

Answer (score 1):

Any element of $C$ have at most 2 elements:

suppose it has 3 distinct elements $x > y > z$, $x - y$ and $y - z$ must be $1$ but then $x - z = 2$ which is absurd. So it's easier to count them now.

For $D$, $(0, 1) \in D$ so $|D| \ge \mathfrak c$. In fact, every subset of $(0, 1)$ is in $D$, so $|D| \ge 2^{|(0,1)|} = 2^{\mathfrak c}$ so you can deduce the result.